# Image link upload is broken

Tags: bug

Trying to add an image from a link to a PNG is broken. It works if you download the image and re-upload it. When adding the link, it gives the error:

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

Yet, the placeholder text ends with PNG, and uploading the file directly without alterations also works. The link is

http://www.candidayeastinfection.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/spit-test.png

Comment: I have tried uploading PNG images from *other* sites - this works. I suspect the issue here is with the site (it probably rejects image download requests that are not directly from a browser - though I did not test that).

Comment: @Oded fair enough, I wasn't aware of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89228/178179 , which I disagree but I don't mind.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - no worries... but... as you can see - this got attention ;)

Comment: @Oded it did, however it reached a tiny fraction of the audience it would have had on mse. But I understand moving questions around may confuse users.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - not really the point. Sure, it can get a larger audience, but the main audience for the [meta-tag:bug] tag is SE developers, and we see these on any meta they are raised on.

Comment: @Oded True, but often reported bugs aren't bugs, and thereby of interest of people who want to know more on how SE works. On healthy SE websites, people typically advise such questions to be posted on MSE.